# Listing shared files with Google Drive API

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I'm having trouble getting a list of files *shared with me* using the Google Drive API.  I am going off the code from the docs here.
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list

It works for listing files that I have created.  For instance my initial request looks like this to show files that haven't been trashed.  This works fine for me.

```
var initialRequest = gapi.client.request({
    'path': '/drive/v2/files',
    'method': 'GET',
    'params': {"q": "mimeType != 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false"}
});
```

But if I try to show files *shared with me* like this it returns an empty list of items.

```
var initialRequest = gapi.client.request({
    'path': '/drive/v2/files',
    'method': 'GET',
    'params': {"q": "sharedWithMe"}
});
```

However sending the request https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q=sharedWithMe in Google's OAuth 2.0 Playground does work and the response contains a list of all files *shared with me*.

I do not understand why it works in the Playground and not on my website.

Comment: The playground makes requests on the backend. Maybe it is a problem with the client library. Can you confirm that the URLs are the same from the playground and from the client call? Thanks

Comment: Hi Ali, thanks for your reply.  Yes, the links are correct.  It's not a problem with the client library because even if I try a simple jQuery ajax GET request to https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q=sharedWithMe I get an empty list of items while something like https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q=trashed%3Dfalse works fine.  Could it be a problem with my API project?

Comment: Hi Ali, could the problem be with permissions?  I am using .file + .install + .appdata for drive.  The files that were shared with me were created by the same app but it doesn't work unless you let the app have full permissions.